# SQL Join multiple dismiss same values if one is false

Tags: mysql, sql, join, between

these are examples my tables:

```
Employees
id     | Name 
1      | employee 1   
2      | employee 2    
3      | employee 3    

Busy_Schedule
id     | start_date  | finish_date | employee_id
1      | 20-11-2017  | 22-11-2017  | 1 
2      | 24-11-2017  | 28-11-2017  | 1
3      | 20-11-2017  | 22-11-2017  | 2    
4      | 20-11-2017  | 22-11-2017  | 3
```

I want to choose available employees based on joining these two tables.

For example, I want to know who is available from 21-11-2017 to 23-11-2017.
If I use join, I am getting employee 1 as available because of the multiple entries, whereas he is not available between these two dates.

I am working with Mysql

Comment: What SQL query you've tried?

Comment: Post your query.

Comment: Thank you sirs. I was going to post my query but my question has been answered by Mr. Juan. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the dates ranges overlaps.

[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

So when you know what employees are busy on those days, just select the employees `NOT IN` that group.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Employees 
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT employee_id
                   FROM Busy_Schedule
                   WHERE start_date  <= '2017-11-23'
                     AND finish_date >= '2017-11-21')
```

Comment: Great.Thank you sir, the answer was so simple while i was trying to complicate things.